# Pole on the Real Axis of Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Save me! SOS!. Please see image. I'm completely baffled about how to go about solving this. Please can you explain the how you get -pi*i from the 4th line?

Can you please explain by this paragraph as simply as possible (found on image)

"Now we take the limit R → ∞ and, with m = 1 Jordan’s Lemma tell us that
R HR= 0 because the only singularity is a pole and the integrand decays to zero as R → ∞. Given that the small circle has the equation z = r(cos θ + i sin θ) for θ : π → 0, and noting that sin θ ≥ 0 in this range"

Please see 1st & 2nd image for full context

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGWk3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVU5h.png)

Comment: It would help if you could describe explicitly the set up, i.e. what each of the contour's stand for. In any case, Jordan's lemma gives an upper bound to for the remainder term which depends on R, but the upper bound decays to 0 as R goes to infinity, so thus the term itself (which is bounded above by an expression going to zero) must also go to zero.

Comment: I've added the full context

Comment: "See image"...what image? What's the question?

Comment: Apologies, please see updates

Answer (score 0):

In any case, Jordan's lemma gives an upper bound for the remainder term which depends on R, but the upper bound decays to 0 as R goes to infinity, so thus the term itself (which is bounded above by an expression going to zero) must also go to zero.

See the section "Applications of Jordan's Lemma" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma.

I.e. we want the contour integral along the half-circle to "go away" or "disappear", and Jordan's Lemma shows us that we can, in fact, disregard it *in the limit as $R \to \infty$.*

Also the link to the proof you are referring to is gone, so I'm not certain, but generally speaking the term $-\pi i$ will come from integrating $\frac{1}{z}$ half-way around the origin in the clockwise direction, since the integral the full-way around in the counter-clockwise direction is $2\pi i$, if you recall.

In these types of proofs the integral half-way around the origin will "become the integral along the real line" as $R \to \infty$, provided the other terms drop out, which they do by applying Jordan's Lemma.

Comment: Still not understanding what you mean. Please can you elaborate further

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking, so it's hard for me to elaborate more or to be more specific. If you could write out the section of the proof in the question which you don't understand, as well as the statement of the theorem which you are trying to prove, it would make it much easier to help you.